# Geocoding using Google Geocoding Web Service

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, google-geocoder

I'm trying to geocode an address from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 using Javascript.
I don't want to display the map, just perform the Geocoding and store the Lat / Long values in the database.
I keep getting an error message saying

> "result.0 is null or not an object"

```
var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=39 George Street, Belmont, WA, 6104, Australia&sensor=false'

var lat = url.results[0].geometry.location.lat();

alert(lat)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that this is a complete code snippet. On that assumption your code is incomplete. Your code creates a string called `url`. You then attempt to access a collection in that string, called `results` (which does not exist - and therefore position 0 within that colelction does not exist). Basically, your code doesn't do anything.

You need to have a good read of the Google Geocode API because, I'm sorry to say, you're not even close to getting this working... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Edit:
In the interests of being more helpful - here is a walkthrough too: http://www.wikihow.com/Geocode-an-Address-in-Google-Maps-Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with Greg...you appear to have the request URL pretty close.  Check out the [Google Geocoding guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) for the exacts.  What you will get back is a JSON string, so you should use something like [jQuery to parse the string into an object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

If you are not set on using JSON, then a simple script like this will also return the Lat/Lng (adapted from [Google sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes)):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var geocoder;

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var addressLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
        alert("Lat: " + addressLocation.lat() + " Lon: " + addressLocation.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: ...thanks and as I re-read your answer, I realized that the code in the question really was pretty far from working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you guys understand my question. I need to use javascript to geocode my addresses as I'm trying to do this from a customized ribbon button in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. Therefore, I get a "google is not defined" error if I try to use the above code. How do I load the Geocode web service from javascript and get the result back to store the lat / long in my database? I cannot use a html page for this.

Comment: You are going to have to convert the script to your needs.  There are blog posts describing how to [call scripts in webresources](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/using-javascript-in-a-custom-button-in-crm-2011/).  You might also want to look at the [Bing Maps in Codeplex](http://edgewaters.blogspot.com/2011/07/bing-map-browser-for-crm-2011.html).  It has a built-in address lookup feature.